# Exception handling for a chain of prompts

Tags: python, error-handling, console

I am trying to make an `inputin()` function to take all the parameters input for the first time with exception and for individual parameter for the runtime proposition. I am thus looking forward to reducing code size or being a more efficient coder with more pythonic procedures.

""This code is well executed and tested for all possible situations""

```
import turtle              # 1.  import the modules
#import random

BackGround = 'white'
Numside = 0
Armlen = 0
Turtlecolor = 'blue'
Turtleshape = 'turtle'

def inputin(count = 1, port = 0):
            #counting for resolving runtime error
    global BackGround, Numside, Armlen, Turtlecolor, Turtleshape

    while True :
        try :
            if((port == 0 or port == count) and count == 1):
                count+=1
                BackGround = str(input("Enter the Background Color : "))
            if((port == 0 or port == count) and count == 2):
                count+=1
                Numside = int(input("Enter the No. of Sides : "))
            if((port == 0 or port == count) and count == 3):
                count+=1
                Armlen = int(input("Enter the length of each side : "))
            if((port == 0 or port == count) and count == 4):
                count+=1
                Turtlecolor = str(input("Enter the Turtle Color : "))
            if((port == 0 or port == count) and count == 5):
                count+=1
                Turtleshape = str(input("Enter the Turtle Shape : "))
            port = -1
            break
        except ValueError :
            print("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")
            count+=-1

#Creating Screen after Everything Is Over


#i am creting this class for adjusting multiple values like a structure.
class Team(object):
    def __init__(self, Numside = 0, Armlen = 0, Turtlecolor = "", Turtleshape = ""):
        self.Numside = Numside
        self.Armlen = Armlen
        self.Turtlecolor = Turtlecolor
        self.Turtleshape = Turtleshape

def screen():
    wn = turtle.Screen()       # 2.  Create a screen

    while True:
        try:
            wn.bgcolor(BackGround)
            break
        except turtle.TurtleGraphicsError as e:
            inputin(1,1)

    wn.exitonclick()

def TurtleCreation():
    lance = turtle.Turtle()
    while True:
        positionInput = 0 #for marking the position of the desired input  
        try:
            positionInput = 4
            lance.color(Turtlecolor)
            positionInput = 5
            lance.shape(Turtleshape)
            break
        except turtle.TurtleGraphicsError as f:
            inputin(positionInput,positionInput)
    lance.speed(500)
    lance.penup()
    #lance.goto(-300,200)


inputin()
TurtleCreation()
screen()


#sc = turtle.ScrolledCanvas(master)

#now shifting the turtle to the middle of the system
```

Comment: `count+=-1`?! You came to the right place...

Comment: So you really expect the function to be called with non-default parameters? Also, are `BackGround`, `Numside`, etc. local variables?

Answer (score 3):

The whole `port` and `count` thing is a total waste of time. If you *were* stuck with it:

- `port` is redundant, as `break` is what actually ends the loop;
- If `port` *was* being used (e.g. `while port:`) it should be a `bool` (`True`/`False`) rather than an `int` (`1`/`0`);
- You shouldn't have whitespace around the `=` for default argument values (`def inputin(count=1, port=0):`);
- The `if` conditions should have more space and fewer parentheses: `if port == 0 and count == 3:`; and
- `count+=-1` should be `count -= 1`.

Only two of your inputs actually need to be numbers, yet you wrap the whole thing in `try`; that block should be *as short as you can make it*. You can factor out the integer inputs for much cleaner code (see e.g. [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761)). For the other three inputs the return from `input` is *always a string*, so the `str` calls are totally redundant.

Compare:

```
def int_input(prompt):
    """Validate integer-only user input."""
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an integer.")

def input_in():
    """Get required user inputs."""
    background = input("Enter the background color: ")
    num_sides = int_input("Enter the number of sides: ")
    arm_len = int_input("Enter the length of each side: ")
    turtle_color = input("Enter the turtle color: ")
    turtle_shape = input("Enter the turtle shape: ")
    ...
```

Note the adherence to [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and use of [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to explain what each function does.

As additional exercises:

- Add limits to the integer validation, allowing a minimum and maximum to be set for the function (a negative `arm_len` wouldn't make much sense, for example);
- Create a `color_input` function to validate the user's color selection, and use it where appropriate; and
- Create a `shape_input` function to do the same for shapes.

Comment: Just use the latest version of the full code snippet for further reviews and suggestions